# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I restarted my Ubuntu 12.04 today (after a month or so for which it was continuously on :P) and it's not working. I am thinking of installing Ubuntu 14.04 along with the currently installed 12.04 and windows for the time being and debug 12.04 later.

How should I partition my disk in this case? I have created an empty partition (currently unallocated) of size 100GB. Do I need separate swap areas for the 2 versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the whole 100 GB for Ubuntu 14.04.

You do not need additional swap areas, because both versions will recognize the swap partition automatically (during installation) and use it.

I'm not sure how it works when you suspend on (because it suspends into swap) and boot the other one. If you automatically boot the suspenden one, don't worry.